# NSFetchResultsController shows spurious objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITableView showing objects from a Core Data entity that are received from a WebServer, through a `NSFetchResultController`. The user can modify them and send them back to the server. She also can tap a button to refresh those objects from the server.

Each object has an identifier attribute. When I receive an object JSON from the server, I look for an existing object with that same identifier. It it exists, I update it. Otherwise I create it.

Some of this is happening with a Main Queue `NSManagedObjectContext`, some of it in a child Private Queue one. In all cases, it happens in a `performBlock` method and both the child context and its parent is saved.

This sounds like bread and butter Core Data patterns. Now my issue:

Sometimes, after a server refresh, the `NSFetchResultController` shows two instances of the same object. The two copies are distinct (their pointers are different). One copy is complete, the other only has its attribute values set, not its relations. Both have the same `NSManagedObjectContext`. Both have the same identifier.

How can I debug such an issue? I checked that my CoreData store does *not* have two instances of the same object (by looking inside the SQLite file, and also by putting a symbolic breakpoint on `awakeFromInsert`). I traced through the code that looks for the existing instance and it finds it alright.

At this point, I am stuck, and I have a hard time imagining a debugging strategy.

I can provide all the details imaginable, but beside showing the full source code, I am not sure what would be the most useful.

Thanks for any help.

JD

Edit 1: Here is my `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:(DaySlotCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

Edit 2: here is how my contexts are arranged. I have a central singleton model object that takes care of communication with the remote server (thus its class name `SGIServer`). It holds two contexts:

- `mainManagedObjectContext`, a `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`, is used for all UI-related stuff, included the `NSFetchResultController` described above (even though I read on the net that an `NSFetchResultController` can use a private context). It is not associated with the persistent store. It is a child of:
- `persistentManagedObjectContext`, a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, associated with the persistent store, in charge of saving to the store in the background:

They are created at launch time like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator;
self.persistentManagedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
managedObjectContext.parentContext = self.persistentManagedObjectContext;
self.mainManagedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
```

Code that needs a context do so in two different ways depending if they want the main context or not:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [server mainManagedObjectContext];
```

or

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [server newPrivateContext];
```

where `newPrivateContext` simply creates a new `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` context, child of the main one:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) newPrivateContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *privateContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    privateContext.parentContext = self.mainManagedObjectContext;
    return privateContext;
}
```

Finally, I defined two `save` methods, a synchronous one and an asynchronous one:

```
- (void)syncSaveContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) moc persisting:(BOOL)saveToDisk
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = self.mainManagedObjectContext;

    if (moc && moc != mainContext) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![moc save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving MOC: %@\n%@",[error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        }
    }

    if (mainContext && [mainContext hasChanges]) {
        [mainContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![mainContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Error saving MOC: %@\n%@",[error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
    }
    if (saveToDisk) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *privateContext = self.persistentManagedObjectContext;

        if (privateContext && [privateContext hasChanges]) {
            [privateContext performBlockAndWait: ^{
                NSError *error = nil;
                if (![privateContext save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Error saving private MOC: %@\n%@",[error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
- (void)asyncSaveContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) moc persisting:(BOOL)saveToDisk
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = self.mainManagedObjectContext;

    if (moc && moc != mainContext) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![moc save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving MOC: %@\n%@",[error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        }
    }

    if (mainContext && [mainContext hasChanges]) {
        [mainContext performBlock:^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            if ([mainContext save:&error]) {
                if (saveToDisk) {
                    NSManagedObjectContext *privateContext = self.persistentManagedObjectContext;

                    if (privateContext && [privateContext hasChanges]) {
                        [privateContext performBlock: ^{
                            NSError *error = nil;
                            if (![privateContext save:&error]) {
                                NSLog(@"Error saving private MOC: %@\n%@",[error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
                            }
                        }];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error saving MOC: %@\n%@",[error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

The async one is the most used one, typically at the end of any user-triggered action.
The sync one is occasionally used when I want to make sure the save has been done before I continue.

Comment: do you have code for ``(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath``? provide it please

Comment: yes, the most common one. See my edit

Comment: Have you tried to debug with breakpoint at ``NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert``?

Comment: This is almost certainly not an issue with the FRC itself.  It sounds to me like you are modifying objects in two contexts and you are not correctly merging between them.  Please provide details on how your contexts are arranged and how you are using them.

Comment: NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert is indeed called, but this doesn't seem to lead me anywhere. At that point the call stack is devoid from any of my code.

Comment: context details added. Hopefully enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have some kind of two context set up (parent and child, main queue and private queue) and this tends to happen after calling save on your contexts then you may have a similar problem to something I had where temporary objects are leaking in to your context.  As far as I'm aware this is a bug in core data

Where you call save, try calling `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects` inside your parent context perform block like this:

```
[self.parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError * error = nil;
            [self.parentContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:[self.parentContext.insertedObjects allObjects] error:&error];
            [self.parentContext save: &error]
        }];
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement the suggestion and come back with feedback

Comment: That was it. This simple change before I save any context (thus in my two save methods shown in my question) eliminated any occurence of spurious lines. I am not even sure that they occurred upon save (as I save often and early), so this feels a bit like voodoo, but I could not reproduce the problem now. Thank you very much

Comment: Yea it's a horrible problem.  I spent a couple of days tracking it down until I found a bug report in some obscure place.  Glad it worked!